# MongoDB mongorestore failure: locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

Tags: mongodb, locale, ubuntu-12.04, mongodump, mongorestore

I created a dump with mongodump on computer A (ubuntu 12.04 server). I moved it to computer B (ubuntu 12.04 server) and typed:

> mongorestore -db db_name --drop db_dump_path

It failed and it reported:

> connected to: 127.0.0.1
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
>   what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
>   Aborted

I've successfully accomplished this operation before and this strange behavior has never occurred. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Actually it isn't strictly related to MongoDB. Somehow the language on computer B was not defined correctly. I managed to fix it by typing:

> sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
>   sudo locale-gen it_IT it_IT.UTF-8
>   sudo locale-gen xx_xx xx_XX.UTF-8 ...
>   sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

These commands will generate and configure the needed locales.
After those steps mongorestore got back working as usual.

Comment: this basically helped me. but also had to edit `/etc/locale.gen` and enable the needed locales (on arch linux)

Comment: This solved the problem for me too. This is on Lubuntu 12.04 x86.

Comment: But why is this happening, is there any specific reasons that mongodump / restore depends on locale languages ?

Comment: @MarianTheisen That was the culprit for me as well, I'm on a fresh Arch install and got the error while trying to run rescuetime. Fixing `/etc/locale.gen` and running `locale-gen` was all that was required.

Answer (score 259):

On my distro "locale-gen" was not installed and it turned out all I had to do is set the LC_ALL environment variable.
so the following command fixed it:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

hopefully it will help someone else...

Comment: This works fine in a terminal session, but if you look for a permanent solution you'd rather check http://stackoverflow.com/a/32762296/82609

Comment: Thanks @SebastienLorber, in my case I added this line to my ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc and it worked permanently

Comment: Hmmm, came here just prior to reading that setting LC_ALL is strongly discouraged: https://wiki.debian.org/Locale

Comment: Damn, but this LC_ALL setting solved the problem right and there, instantly and without requiring root privileges. Nevermind, hopefully there won't be any darkness bugs haunting me later.

Answer (score 17):

Exporting `LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"` only works if you have the `en_US` locale installed. If you want to avoid installing the `locales` package (or its equivalent on distributions other than Debian derivatives), then you can instead use:

```
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

which will not require any extra locale data.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using a Mac OSX and SSH this might be issued by wrong LC_CTYPE.

```
$ locale 
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Unset the wrong var.

```
$ unset LC_CTYPE
```

Check whether locale is working fine.

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Now mongo also should do fine.

Comment: Works like a charm. Very native and fast.

Comment: @user1219736 You saved my day :P

Answer (score 10):

To make the fix permanent you can edit one of those files:

- sudo vim /etc/default/locale
- sudo vim /etc/environment

And add the line `LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: this worked for me (centos, AWS c4.8xlarge, helped with vivado starting fix)

Answer (score 9):

Got same problem on debian 7 without locale-gen (command not found) installed.

I solved this way:

```
su
apt-get install locales
dpkg-reconfigure locales # select locales you want!
```

Now mongodb should start.

[Source](http://hexample.com/2012/02/05/fixing-locale-problem-debian/)