# Meteor: unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting. What is this?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

The title pretty much says it - when I try to start a newly created meteor app, this appears when starting the proxy and I get the message that the mongo server can't be started.

I created some swap space already (that was mentioned in the only other thread realted to that problem) and even reinstalled it - no further success.
Weird thing is, on my normal laptop this works. The laptop I'm having trouble with is a Pentium III with 1GB RAM, maybe this matters.

Any thoughts? Is the machine too old?

EDIT:

My setup:
Thinkpad T23, PIII 1.13 GHz, 1GB RAM.
Debian Stretch/testing, Linux Kernel 4.1.0-1-686-pae

My log:

`[[[[[ ~/Server/sample ]]]]]
=>  Started proxy.
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.
Can't start Mongo Server.`

Comment: Can you post logs and errors when you start meteor app

Comment: Sure, I'll do my best. See in the main question.

Answer (score 4):

> This command will reset your database

`meteor reset`

Comment: Tried that yesterday already, no different results. I mean why reset, the DB can't even start up

Comment: This did to the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting your `LANG` environment variable? As shown in [Mongo can't be started when starting Meteor](http://meteor-universal.tumblr.com/post/111436375884/mongo-cant-be-started-when-launching-meteor), which explains the following:

<snip>

If you get an error like

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.
...
Can't start Mongo server.
```

the solution is very easy but not easy to know:

You have not set your `LANG` settings in current shell.

Set your `LANG` env vars before starting meteor manually or permanent in your profile settings.

```
export LANG=C
export LC_ALL=C
```

Now you can run meteor and it should be able to start the mongo development process.

</snip>

It might be worth trying. HTH.

Comment: The file doesn't even exist - it just gets generated if the mongoDB actually starts up at least one time. Besides, as you see, it's exit code 100, not null.

Comment: Good idea, but didn't work. Is there somewhere something like a log for this?

Comment: I'm not sure about the logs specifically for the LANG env var, but you could take a peek at logs under /var/log. Possibly /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages, but I'm not certain. I also found some info on a related SO post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100708/mongodb-mongorestore-failure-localefacet-s-create-c-locale-name-not-valid when I googled  '_S_create_c_locale name not valid', so I'll update my answer to reflect that approach.

Comment: Thinking about this more, I'm wondering if you could try debugging it using gdb. Determine the pid of running meteor and then issue `gdb attach pid`. There's more alternatives shown at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308653/can-i-use-gdb-to-debug-a-running-process.

Comment: I see, I see... but hasn't helped :/ I don'T get these error messages, in fact, I get none at all. It's really just what I wrote in my starting post.  
Haha wait, I'll try my best with gdb.

Comment: My mistake. I was reading my own answer too closely instead of your original. I'm out of ideas, so you might try gdb and post any results here.

Answer (score 2):

I think your suspicion about the machine being too old is correct.

You can reproduce the same error by trying to build a meteor app on a digitalocean droplet with 512mb of ram. On an otherwise identical machine with 8gb of ram, the app builds without error.

Comment: It certainly does not work with the 521mb droplet. :(

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the @w=majority param in your connection string